How to combine 3 for loops into 1?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  
    int count = 1; 
    
    // Declaring 3D array 
    int array1[3][4][5]; 
  
    // Initialize 3D array using loop 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) { 
                  array1[i][j][k] = count; 
                  count++; 
            }
        } 
    } 
  
    // Printing the element of 3D array 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { 
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) { 
            cout <<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<k <<" "<< array1[i][j][k] << " "<<endl;
           } 
        } 
        cout << endl; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}

Output:
0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 2 
0 0 2 3 
0 0 3 4 
0 0 4 5 
0 1 0 6 
0 1 1 7 
0 1 2 8 
0 1 3 9 
0 1 4 10 
0 2 0 11 
0 2 1 12 
0 2 2 13 
0 2 3 14 
0 2 4 15 
0 3 0 16 
0 3 1 17 
0 3 2 18 
0 3 3 19 
0 3 4 20 

1 0 0 21 
1 0 1 22 
1 0 2 23 
1 0 3 24 
1 0 4 25 
1 1 0 26 
1 1 1 27 
1 1 2 28 
1 1 3 29 
1 1 4 30 
1 2 0 31 
1 2 1 32 
1 2 2 33 
1 2 3 34 
1 2 4 35 
1 3 0 36 
1 3 1 37 
1 3 2 38 
1 3 3 39 
1 3 4 40 

2 0 0 41 
2 0 1 42 
2 0 2 43 
2 0 3 44 
2 0 4 45 
2 1 0 46 
2 1 1 47 
2 1 2 48 
2 1 3 49 
2 1 4 50 
2 2 0 51 
2 2 1 52 
2 2 2 53 
2 2 3 54 
2 2 4 55 
2 3 0 56 
2 3 1 57 
2 3 2 58 
2 3 3 59 
2 3 4 60 

I tried the below code to make a single loop. Please note, the count increments correctly but I'm not getting the correct i,j,k values:
int main() 
{ 
    int count = 1; 
    
    // Declaring 3D array 
    int array1[3][4][5]; 
  
    for (int ijk = 0; ijk < 3 * 4 * 5; ijk++) {
        array1[ijk / 4][ijk / 4][ijk % 4] = count; **//Maybe this logic is not correct**
        count++;
    }   

    // Printing the element of 3D array 
    for (int ijk = 0; ijk < 3 * 4 * 5; ijk++) {
        cout << ijk / 4 << " " << ijk / 4 << " " << ijk % 4 << " " << array1[ijk / 4][ijk / 4][ijk % 4] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}

Output:
0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 2 
0 0 2 3 
0 0 3 4 
1 1 0 5 
1 1 1 6 
1 1 2 7 
1 1 3 8 
2 2 0 9 
2 2 1 10 
2 2 2 11 
2 2 3 12 
3 3 0 13 
3 3 1 14 
3 3 2 15 
3 3 3 16 
4 4 0 17 
4 4 1 18 
4 4 2 19 
4 4 3 20 
5 5 0 21 
5 5 1 22 
5 5 2 23 
5 5 3 24 
6 6 0 25 
6 6 1 26 
6 6 2 27 
6 6 3 28 
7 7 0 29 
7 7 1 30 
7 7 2 31 
7 7 3 32 
8 8 0 33 
8 8 1 34 
8 8 2 35 
8 8 3 36 
9 9 0 37 
9 9 1 38 
9 9 2 39 
9 9 3 40 
10 10 0 41 
10 10 1 42 
10 10 2 43 
10 10 3 44 
11 11 0 45 
11 11 1 46 
11 11 2 47 
11 11 3 48 
12 12 0 49 
12 12 1 50 
12 12 2 51 
12 12 3 52 
13 13 0 53 
13 13 1 54 
13 13 2 55 
13 13 3 56 
14 14 0 57 
14 14 1 58 
14 14 2 59 
14 14 3 60 


Maybe this logic is not correct This logic is definitely incorrect.

I tried the below code to make a single loop -- One question -- why do you believe you need to write a single loop?  What benefit is there in making the code less readable?

C++ 23 has std::cartesian_product that might help you out

Do some basic calculations first. ijk / 4 will go from 0 to (345-1)/4 = 59/4 = 14, and ijk % 4 from 0 to 3. These are clearly wrong. Also, the absence of both 3 and 5, and the use of ijk / 4 for two dimensions, is a strong indicator of incorrectness.

It looks like you want this:
array1[ijk / (5 * 4)][(ijk / 5) % 4][ijk % 5] = count++;
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
//           i              j           k


k = ijk % 5 - the remainder of the division by the array size
j = (ijk / 5) % 4 - divide by the inner array size and then the remainder of the division by the current array size.
i = ijk / (5 * 4) - divide by the combined size of the two inner arrays

Demo
Note that both readability/maintainability and performance will suffer by doing this.

A better option would be to use range-based for loops which is generally considered safer (since you don't risk accessing the arrays out of bounds) and easier to read:
// Initialize 3D array using loop 
for (auto& ia : array1) {      // auto& ia = int(&ia)[4][5]
    for (auto& ja : ia) {      // auto& ja = int(&ja)[5]
        for (auto& kv : ja) {  // auto& kv = int& kv
            kv = count++;
        }
    }
}

Here's a performance comparison between the different versions made at quick-bench.com where you can see that your original loop and the range-based loop are equally fast but the loop using divisions and remainder operations is 42(!) times slower:


Perfect.. This is what I wanted.

for (int ijk = 0; ijk < 3 * 4 * 5; ijk++) {
array1[ijk / (5 * 4)] [(ijk / 5) % 4][ijk % 5] = count++;//array1[ijk / 5][ijk / 5][ijk % 5] = count; //Maybe this logic is not correct**
//count++;
}
// Printing the element of 3D array 
for (int ijk = 0; ijk < 3 * 4 * 5; ijk++) {
    cout << ijk / (5*4) << " " << (ijk / 5)%4 << " " << ijk % 5 << " " << array1[ijk / (5 * 4)] [(ijk / 5) % 4][ijk % 5] ;
    cout << endl;
}


@bashar Glad to hear it! I didn't understand your second comment though. What is that about?

Take advantage of modulo arithmetic.
There's 60 total iterations (5x4x3).  Let index between between 0..59

The inner loop is rotating on k from 0..4.  Or index % 5
The outer loop is incrementing i every 20 iteration. Or index/20
The middle loop is tricky. It's incrementing by 1 on each 5th iteration of the inner loop, but resets to 0 when incrementing on each 4th middle. It's effectively: (index/5)%4

Hence...
Initialize:
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    array[i/20][(i/5)%4][i%5] = i;
}

Printing:
for (int x = 0; i < 60; x++) {
    int i = x/20;
    int j = (x/5)%4;
    int k = x%5;

    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k " " << array1[i][j][k] << std::endl;

}


Here an answer (based on this post) that can generalize for N dimensions:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t...SIZES>
constexpr auto get_indexes (std::size_t globalIdx)
{
    // we define the number of entries
    constexpr std::size_t N = (1 * ... * SIZES);

    // we compute the dimensions of the successive parts of the tensor
    std::array<std::size_t,sizeof...(SIZES)> dims { SIZES... };
    for (std::size_t i=1; i<dims.size(); ++i)  { dims[i] *= dims[i-1]; }

    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    {
        // we demultiplex the different indexes from the global index 
        return std::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(SIZES)> {{ ( (globalIdx*std::get<Is>(dims)) / N) % SIZES... }};

    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(SIZES)>{});
}


int main() 
{ 
    // Declaring 3D array 
    int array1[3][4][5]; 
 
    int count = 1;
     
    for (std::size_t n=0; n<3*4*5; n++)
    {
        // we retrieve the different indexes from the "global" index.
        auto [i,j,k] = get_indexes<3,4,5> (n);
        
        array1[i][j][k] = count++;
    }

    for (std::size_t n=0; n<3*4*5; n++)
    {
        // we retrieve the different indexes from the "global" index.
        auto [i,j,k] = get_indexes<3,4,5> (n);
        
        std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k <<" "<< array1[i][j][k] << "\n";
    }
  
     return 0; 
}

Demo
and for a full generic example:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// retrieve an array holding the extent value of the provided array type
template<typename T>
constexpr auto extents ()
{
    return []<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return std::array<std::size_t, std::rank_v<T>>{{ std::extent_v<T,Is>... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::rank_v<T>>());
}

// compute the product of the extents of the provided array type
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t prod_extent ()
{
    return []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    {
        return (1 * ... * std::extent_v<T,Is>); 
    } (std::make_index_sequence<std::rank_v<T>>{});
}

// compute the "digits" of a provided index
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_indexes (std::size_t globalIdx, std::array<std::size_t,N> const& dims)
{
    std::size_t P=1;  for (auto n: dims) { P*=n; }

    std::array<std::size_t,N> coeff  = dims;
    for (std::size_t i=1; i<coeff.size(); ++i)  { coeff[i] *= coeff[i-1]; }

    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    {
        // we demultiplex the different indexes from the global index 
        return std::array<std::size_t, N> {{ ( (globalIdx*std::get<Is>(coeff)) / P) % dims[Is]... }};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto get_indexes_for_array (std::size_t globalIdx)
{
    return get_indexes (globalIdx, extents<T> ());
}

// retrieve an item of a multi-dimensional array from an array of indexes.
template<typename T, typename Idx, int N=0>
constexpr decltype(auto) get (T & arr, Idx const& indexes)
{
    if constexpr (N==std::tuple_size_v<Idx>)   { return arr; }
    else 
    {  
        decltype(auto) current = arr[indexes[N]];
        return get<decltype(current), Idx, N+1> (current, indexes); 
    }
}

constexpr auto ii = get_indexes(310,std::array<size_t,4> {3,4,5,6}); 
static_assert (std::get<0>(ii) == 2);
static_assert (std::get<1>(ii) == 2);
static_assert (std::get<2>(ii) == 1);
static_assert (std::get<3>(ii) == 4);

int main() 
{ 
    int array1[3][4][5][6];  

    using type = decltype(array1);
    
    constexpr std::size_t N = prod_extent<type> ();
    
    int count = 0;     
    for (std::size_t n=0; n<N; n++)
    {
        // we retrieve the different indexes from the "global" index.
        auto idx = get_indexes_for_array <type> (n);
        
        // we set the value of the corresponding item in the array
         get(array1,idx) = count++;
    }

    for (std::size_t n=0; n<N; n++)
    {
        // we retrieve the different indexes from the "global" index.
        auto idx = get_indexes_for_array <type> (n);

        for (auto i : idx)  { std::cout << i << " "; }
        std::cout << get(array1,idx) << "\n";
    }
 
    return 0; 
}

Demo
If you use for instance int array1[2][2][2][2][2];, then get_indexes_for_array<decltype(array1)> is an insane way of getting the bits of the first 32 integers :)

I don't think my answer will really help you as it alters how you have to access the matrix, but it may be a good hint.
I work with a framework where multidimensional arrays are allowed, the number of dimensions is variable.
One solution to solve that is to store the matrix in a flat, 1-dimensional array and calculate the array positions from the matrix indexes.
So the index calculations are pretty much the same but the other way around.
The design decision depends on the most common use cases for your matrix.
In such an environment it is easy to have only one loop for all array elements:
for(int i = 0; i < 3*4*5; i++)
The challenge is to identify to which matrix indexes the array index belongs to or vice versa.
x =  i / (4 * 5)     ; // "% 3" is obsolete, as the result is between 0 and 2
y = (i /      5 ) % 4;
z =  i            % 5; // "/ 1" is obsolete

I guess the generic pattern is clear.
